# Imports - functions with the same name but from different package

Tags: r, namespaces, r-package

I'm working on update of my package. However I'm struggling with dependencies/imports. I use two conflicted packages - `ggplot2` and `psych` and their functions `alpha` and of course `alpha` object of `ggplot2` differs from `alpha` function of `psych` package.

When building package I get an warning:

`Warning: replacing previous import 'ggplot2::alpha' by 'psych::alpha' when loading 'ShinyItemAnalysis'`

Hence I wont be able to publish my package on CRAN (untill I solved this warning). Is there any easy way how to avoid this import conflict?

Comment: define each `alpha` as shown in warning...? `psych::alpha` Vs `ggplot2::alpha`?

Comment: Why are you calling `library` directly? I think it's generally better to either `importFrom(pkg,func)` in `NAMESPACE` or call them directly as `pkg::func` (as well as including them in the `Imports` section in `DESCRIPTION`). Regardless, if you *must*, try `library(psych, warn.conflicts = FALSE)`.

Comment: Actually I use `importFrom(pkg, func)` commands, but this one warning still persists. Well I haven't tried to use `ggplot2::alpha`. I'll try it and let you know if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Now it works! Thank you both for useful comments

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using `roxygen2` package to build `NAMESPACE` from fellow .R scripts, it is very helpful to **delete the `NAMESPACE` file and run `roxygen2` again**. Solves many problems.